# How to structure nested databases in MongoDB

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql

I am trying to structure my database as the following structure in MongoDB

```
Project
 |
 +-- DB1 -- App1
 |            |
 |            +-- Collection1
 |            +-- Collection2
 |            +-- Collection3
 |            +-- Collection4
         -- App2
 |            |
 |            +-- Collection1
 |            +-- Collection2
 |            +-- Collection3
 |            +-- Collection4
 |    
            -- App3
 |            |
 |            +-- Collection1
 |            +-- Collection2
 |            +-- Collection3
 |            +-- Collection4
  +-- DB2 -- App1
 |            |
 |            +-- Collection1
 |            +-- Collection2
 |            +-- Collection3
 |            
 |
  +-- DB3 -- App1
 |            |
 |            +-- Collection1
 |            +-- Collection2
```

---

I am confused as how to nest databases like in the above structure.

My project will contain multiple top-level Database(s) (DB(s) in the above graph), these top level database(s) will further contain sub database(s) (Apps in the above graph). Those individual sub-databases will further contain individual collections.

I was reading this [article](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures/) in the official documentation of MongoDB, where they have nested collection(s). Can we achieve the same for Databases too?

> My questions are:
>
> 1. How to structure nested DB(s)
> 2. Can we have such structure the MongoDB as the above graph
> 3. Is there any best practice to achieve the above.

Comment: What is the goal you want to achieve with "nested DB(s)"? Could you give analogy of "nested DB(s)" from a relational database?

Comment: In a relational database we often link two tables via some column. I want to create a database structure as the above